# adapt input binary mask to itk mesh generator

Tags: c++, itk

I'm trying to generate a mesh from RLE binary mask.
In itk, I find a class named itkBinaryMask3DMeshSource 
it's based on MarchingCubes algorithm

The input should be a 3D binary image

in my case, I have a rle 3D binary mask but represented in 1d vector format.

My function takes as parameters :

1. Inputs : crle 1d vector ( computed rle), dimension Int3
2. Output : coord + coord indices

as a first step, decode the crle : done
the second step, fill the mask into itk data structure, so the itkBinaryMask3DMeshSource , could generate the mesh ; I'm blocked here

any idea

thank you

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://itk.org/ITKExamples/src/Core/Common/CreateAnImage/Documentation.html) is an example of how to manually create an image. After the `image->Allocate()` call [`image->FillBuffer(0)`](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1Image.html#aca0cd1e488bef475a14692d54682f6e5) to have the zero background. Then set the "on" pixels to 255. The slow way is to invoke `image->SetPixel()` for each pixel. The fast way is to use [iterator(s)](https://itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples/Iterators/ImageRegionIterator).

Comment: Thank you, I followed your solution.
just, to set pixels, in itk it's inversed size as zyx
so iterator could be possible
and regarding imageIterator.Set(value); 
since I have 1D array rle of a 3dmask; can continue work with iterator or should I use SetPixel() ?
I appreciate your help

Comment: `imageIterator.Set(value)` is the one you want to use. `SetPixel()` has bad performance.

Comment: thank you a lot, you save my day .
yes, I use imageIterator.Set(value)
now, one thing is left, I can't find in this class how to get the output ( Points and indexes ), so I can used for mesh visualisation. thank you again

Comment: as I see, it's possible de GetNumberOfNodes and GetNumberOfCells
Should I use MeshFileWriter, in order to generate a file, and then I just extract both arrays ( Points and indexes), as in ExtractIsoSurface example ?